# Is there an equivalent to RStudio's ".rs.askForPassword" in Python?

Tags: python, r, password-protection

I want to connect to my database in Python, but i don't want to show my password to other users, like `.rs.askForPassword` does exactly what i need in RStudio. Here's an example:

```
library(RODBC)
conn = odbcConnect(dsn = "my_dsn", 
                   uid = "name.last_name",
                   pwd = .rs.askForPassword("my.password"))
```

Is there any way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use getpass()

```
import getpass

p = getpass.getpass(prompt='What is your favorite person? ')
if p.lower() == 'gf':
    print 'Right.  Off you go.'
else:
    print 'Wrong!'
```